# What kind of variable/hash is this, and how to loop over it?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Downloading the XML
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://meny.no/WebServices/AJAXService.asmx/GetMarkets";
my $content = get($url);

# Creating data from XML
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xml -> XMLin($content);
my $newdata = Dumper($data);
```

So what i wonder about is what type of datastorage do i have with $newdata, and how to loop over the data? I want to insert the data into database.

Comment: `$newdata` is a string showing the contents of `$data` in human readable form in perl syntax. If you print `$newdata` it might very well give you some insight as to what `$data`, the data structure you most likely actually are after, is.

Comment: I assume you would now like to know how to loop through `$data`. But apart from it being a reference to a hash of probably more hashes and arrays, we cannot really know that without seeing the printout of `$newdata`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aDumper)`::Dumper` returns a serialized string representation of a Perl data structure. You can't really loop over a string in a meaningful sense, which makes me wonder why you ran this data through Dumper in the first place. Did you copy the code from somewhere? Generally, Dumper is used when you want to inspect data for debugging purposes or if you want to store data in a Perl-readable format.

The structured data that I presume you want to work with is in the `$data` variable, returned by the XML parser.

Comment: Yes, i removed the Dumper afterwards, I wanna loop over $data.